# Elegant closed form for the eigenvectors of Hermitian Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, classical-mechanics

While working on a problem in Mechanics I came across this closed form solution for the principal directions (which are the eigenvectors of an Hermitian matrix), which I can't wrap my head around. Beware! (index notation).

Let $\sigma$ be an eigenvalue of the stress tensor $\sigma_{ij}$ (known to be Hermitian), a non-trivial solution for the principal direction $n_j$ associated with $\sigma$ must satisfy

\begin{equation}
(\sigma_{ij} - \sigma\delta_{ij}) n_j = 0
\label{eq:condition1}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
n_jn_j =1
\label{eq:condition2}
\tag{2}
\end{equation}

This is the part where I can't follow

Let
\begin{equation}
K = n_1/C_1 = n_2/C_2 = n_3/C_3
\label{eq:K}
\tag{3}
\end{equation}

(how does one arrive at such equality?)

Where $C_i$ is the cofactor of the $i$th column of $\sigma_{ij} - \sigma\delta_{ij}$.

From the first equation of the system given by $\eqref{eq:condition1}$ we have 
\begin{equation}
(\sigma_{11} - \sigma)C_1 K + C_2 K \sigma_{12} + C_3 K\sigma_{13}=0
\label{eq:1st}
\tag{4}
\end{equation}
Since the determinant of $\sigma_{ij} - \sigma\delta_{ij}$ must vanish, expressed in terms of cofactors:
\begin{equation}
(\sigma_{11} - \sigma)C_1  + C_2  \sigma_{12} + C_3 \sigma_{13}=0
\label{eq:determinant}
\tag{5}
\end{equation}

Which is exactly $\eqref{eq:1st}$, indicating the validity of $\eqref{eq:K}$.

$K$ is obtained by subtituting in $\eqref{eq:condition2}$:
\begin{equation}
K = \frac{1}{\sqrt{C_iC_i}}
\end{equation}
Thus the eigenvector is given then by
\begin{equation}
n_j = \frac{C_j}{\sqrt{C_iC_i}}
\end{equation}

My question refers to the formulation of $\eqref{eq:K}$, how do we propose such a factor? I understand that we can work up from $\eqref{eq:determinant}$ up to $\eqref{eq:1st}$ multiplying by an arbitrary constant, but I can't still wrap my head around $\eqref{eq:K}$.

Also this approach fails suddenly when the cofactor vanishes.
No more information is given by the author, the bibliography where this supposedly appears is

Durelli, A J, Philips, E A y Tsao, C H, *Introduction to the Theoretical and Experimental Analysis of Stress and Strain*, McGraw-Hill, New York, **1958**

Sadly I can't get my hands on a copy.

Comment: Small comment, I think we can say the stress tensor is symmetric. As far as I know, everything here is real. The real spectral theorem provides the existence of an orthonormal eigenbasis for a real symmetric matrix. I have not thought through your details...